# d3.js Marker Clustering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, leaflet

I am using an orthographic zoom-able and rotatable globe similar to this: https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/. I need to plot around 20,000 points. Is there a way to cluster markers similar to the way you can using Leaflet?

My current globe uses SVG where each point is a "path" element with a "d" value.

Leaflet example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-markercluster/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Leaflet Markercluster</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.0/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/MarkerCluster.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<!-- Example data. -->
<script src="/mapbox.js/assets/data/realworld.388.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejh2N21nMzAxMmQzMnA5emRyN2lucW0ifQ.jSE-g2vsn48Ry928pqylcg';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
        .setView([-37.82, 175.215], 14)
        .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));

    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
        var a = addressPoints[i];
        var title = a[2];
        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'post', 'marker-color': '0044FF'}),
            title: title
        });
        marker.bindPopup(title);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }

    map.addLayer(markers);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible to do this in d3.js. I quickly found two examples: http://bl.ocks.org/gisminister/10001728 http://codepen.io/smhigley/pen/jifrK/

Comment: @hornj That first example is using a Leaflet map together with Leaflet.markercluster and the second is using Google Maps. I'm wondering if there is a way to marker cluster using the D3.js interactive map linked in my question.

Comment: @persina You just need a data structure that can map the points based on bounding box, maybe an adapated crossfilter.js. 20,000 points will require canvas, keep in mind. https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/using-d3-quadtrees-to-power-an-interactive-map-for-bonnier-corporation/

Comment: @Incodeveritas If I use canvas I will loose the interactivity that SVG allows for.  Being able to target event handlers on DOM elements is a must for zooming and rotating the orthographic projection.  Is there no way to plot 20,000 points on a D3 SVG?

Comment: @persina no, theres not..